# convert textfile into a string in C - hash with md5

Tags: c, string, hash, md5

i want to read in a text file, seperate it and then hash the seperated parts.

Here is my code so far:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include "md5.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <omp.h>

#include <time.h>

#define HASH_LENGTH 16

int main (){

    unsigned char target[HASH_LENGTH] = {0x1c, 0x01, 0x43, 0xc6, 0xac, 0x75, 0x05, 0xc8, 0x86, 0x6d, 0x10, 0x27, 0x0a, 0x48, 0x0d, 0xec}; 
    time_t start = time(NULL);
    FILE* f;
    char c;

    f = fopen("testing.txt", "r");
    if(f == NULL){
        return 1;
                }

    while((c=fgetc(f))!=EOF){
            printf("%c",c);
                }
    fclose(f);

    //char string[] = f;
    const char* delim = " .,;-:0123456789?!\"*+()|&[]#$/%%'";
    char *ptr;

    ptr = strtok(string, delim);

    while(ptr != NULL) {


printf("found part: %s\n", ptr);
    ptr = strtok(NULL, delim);
}
/**
 * unsigned char hash[HASH_LENGTH] = {0};
 * char buffer[1024];

 * MD5_CTX md5_ctx;
 * MD5_Init(&md5_ctx);
 * MD5_Update(&md5_ctx, buffer, strlen(buffer));
 * MD5_Final(hash, &md5_ctx);
 **/

time_t end = time(NULL);
printf("Execution took ~%fs\n", difftime(end, start));
return 0;
```

}

So far i read the file and can print it. Next i want to seperate it with the delimeters into pairs of two words(first and second word as a pair, third and fourth,...). Therefor i want to use strtok(), but i dont know how i can convert the file into a string?

With these new string of pairs i just can use the md5 methods?

Comment: Please don't use md5 ! see: http://www.mscs.dal.ca/~selinger/md5collision/

Comment: `ptr = strtok(string, delim);`what is string ?

Comment: "string" should be the converted string

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this implementation example will help:
https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/24575479/

The Makefile could be found here: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/24575486/